# SERIAL works with NULL, GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY not

Tags: postgresql, identity-column, postgresql-12, table-partitioning

Postgres 12:

```
CREATE TABLE l_table (
    id INT generated always as identity,
    w_id int NOT null references w_table(id),
    primary key (w_id, id)
)PARTITION BY LIST (w_id);

CREATE table l1 PARTITION OF l_table FOR VALUES IN (1);

insert into l1 (w_id) values (1);
```

I'm getting:

```
ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
```

If I replace `INT generated always as identity` with `SERIAL` it **works**. This is odd as in another table the generated always as identity works with null. Using `default` as value does not work either.

GAAI is supposed to be the SQL standard way of replacing SERIAL, even It's the suggested one. What am I missing here?

Comment: Use `insert into l_table (w_id) values (1);` instead - inserting into the partition appears not to default the identity column

Comment: Looks like it works. Please answer this and I'll check it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What am I missing here?

You're trying to insert into the partition table `l1` directly, instead of the partitioned `l_table`. This ignores the identity column on the parent table, tries to insert the default `null`, and fails the non-null constraint that every identity column has. If you instead do

```
insert into l_table (w_id) values (1);
```

it will work and route the inserted row into the right partition.

> Using `default` as value does not work either.

Apparently it's quite hard to do that. [How to DEFAULT Partitioned Identity Column?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/225392/188406) over at dba.SE discusses some workarounds.